# Saving view states with Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, custom-view, savestate

I developed a pretty simple game that uses a custom view for drawing to the screen. On my phone (Android 2.2), I can press the home button on the device and do other tasks. When returning to the game, it is restored to the exact state that it was before. The thing is, I didn't have to override any methods or really do anything for this behavior to occur. However, on Honeycomb, it resets everything like I would expect.

It's very puzzling... I was wondering if there was a way to make Honeycomb behave like 2.2 in this regard. I'm not too familiar with saving view states, but since I have a LOT of variables (hundreds, depending on how custom objects are saved), I imagine it being unpleasant to manually do.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it. Kind of.

Basically, the problem was caused by the way that Android handles the screen being fixed to portrait mode in my activity. In 2.2, Android would open the activity in portrait mode and not restart the activity. However, in Android 3.0, it opens the activity, and THEN rotates the screen, causing it to restart the activity (since that happens when a rotate happens).

To fix this, I added the following to my activity in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

This tells Android that you will handle config changes yourself. In my case, I do nothing, since my application is locked in portrait mode.

The reason the state isn't cleared when the application is paused is because onCreate() doesn't get called. I am aware that Android can kill the application though, which would call onCreate(), so I will still have to handle that situation by saving the Activity variables and recreating the View with them.